# endless loop in perl

Tags: perl

I want to extract the content except http header from tcp flow files
the content is like the following
the http header ends when two ^M are met

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK^M 
Last-Modified: Sat, 20 Mar 2010 09:43:12 GMT^M 
Content-Type: video/x-flv^M 
Date: Wed, 24 Oct 2012 14:34:13 GMT^M 
Expires: Wed, 24 Oct 2012 14:34:13 GMT^M 
Cache-Control: private, max-age=22124^M 
Accept-Ranges: bytes^M 
Content-Length: 29833281^M 
Connection: close^M 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff^M 
Server: gvs 1.0^M 
^M 
FLV^A^E^@^@^@   ^@^@^@^@^R^@^CK^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^B^@ 
onMetaData^H^@^@^@^O^@^Hduration^@@i<97> 
=p£×^@  starttime^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^Mtotalduration^@@i<97>
```

my code for extraction is as follows,
and I run : extract.pl < tcp.flow
but it seems the loop is endless,
what is wrong with the codes? thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
$start=0; 
$data=""; 
while(<STDIN>) 
{ 
    if ( $start eq 0 && $_ =~ /^\r\n/) { $start = 1; } 
    elsif ( $start eq 1 ) { $data = $data . $_; } 
} 
open(FH, ">sample.flv"); 
print FH $data; 
close(FH);
```

Comment: Why not using a standard module like `LWP` or `WWW::Mechanize` to do scraping ?

Comment: Just for semantic correctness's sake, `eq` is the string comparison operator. If you know your values will be ints, you should be using `==`.  Or, better yet, since they're basically booleans, use them as such.  `if (!$start && /^\r\n/) ...`  :P

Comment: Here is a one-liner that essentially does what you want: `perl -E'1 until <> eq "\015\012"; print for <>' <tcp.flow >sample.flv` I split your `while` loop into two, and added a breaking condition to switch between them (the current line has to consist of `\r\n`). It can be golfed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a one-liner. I see no reason for any endless loop, however.

```
perl -00 -lne '$i++ and print' file > sample.flv
```

Which deparsed looks like this:

```
>perl -MO=Deparse -00 -lne '$i++ and print' input.txt
BEGIN { $/ = ""; $\ = "\n\n"; }        # from -l and -00
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {   # from -n
    chomp $_;                          # from -l, removes "\n\n" now
    print $_ if $i++;                  # skips the first line
}
-e syntax OK
```

If you need to clean your file up first, just do

```
perl -pi -le 's/[\r\n]+$//' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `binmode()` on STDIN before reading the data, it's possible that the contents of the file are interfering with the file reading.  You'll want to use it on FH as well before writing the data.  HTH